# Setting drag mode over QGraphicsScene with QGraphicsWebView() in it

Tags: svg, pyqt, drag, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have:

```
self.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self))
self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
```

where self is `QGraphicsView`.  I am opening my svg in QGraphicsWebView() because of it's interactivity like this:

```
s = self.scene()
s.clear()
self.resetTransform()

self.webview = QGraphicsWebView()
self.webview.load(QtCore.QUrl(path_to_my_svg))
self.webview.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemClipsToShape)
self.webview.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.NoCache)
self.webview.setZValue(0)
s.addItem(self.webview)
```

Zooming works fine, but when I click over webview item in order to drag it, nothing happens except cursor is changed to text cursor. I can drag svg only when I open it like `self.svgItem = QtSvg.QGraphicsSvgItem(path_to_my_svg)`  but in that case it's rendered as static image so I lose interactivity in svg(mouseover, mouseout in svg elements)...

**EDIT** based on  xndrme's comment:

As he suggested SHIFT+mouse left click works well, but it drags the whole SVG which is inside `self.webview`. Apparently I've thought that when I zoom with mouse scroll svg gets zoomed, but actually `self.webview` is the one that gets zoomed and scroll bars appears. So, what I've actually need to know is how to drag the whole `self.webview` within its scroll bar boundaries (with left mouse click)

Comment: Had you tried SHIFT+click to drag? It's working for me.

Comment: @xndrme thank you for response. It's working. I've get it all wrong, so I've edited my question, please take a look.